# What causes an issue with desktop elements losing focus when I move my mouse cursor on the left and top screen edges?

Tags: gnome, xfce, mate

I'm trying to investigate this issue for some time now. I'm using Xubuntu and I've noticed that Whisker Menu icon is blinking when I move my mouse cursor on the left and top screen edges, but it behaves normally when I drag it on the bottom and right edges. Not only panel plugins/elements are affected by this, but also other applications, for example Plank.

You can see the issue on this video: https://youtu.be/YXmFXFV_ONQ

Issue occurs on Ubuntu 18.04 (GNOME), Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE and some other distributions like Manjaro Xfce. EDIT: Kubuntu is also affected.

More details (and videos showing this issue) are here: https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?pid=48257

Please help me to kill that nasty bug, it's been on my system for a year now, I've noticed it on Xubuntu 17.04. I don't know where exactly to submit this bug, I previously submitted it wrongly on the Xfce's Bugzilla, but this issue is not Xfce specific, now I know that.

Here are some other videos showing this issue:
Ubuntu MATE - https://streamable.com/ee9sk
Kubuntu - https://streamable.com/dyqur
Xubuntu - https://youtu.be/UY4ZuxsPifw?t=15s

Comment: I'd remove the edit and post it as an answer (you can answer your own questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, there's a workaround for this issue. This bug report tells a lot more about it - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1795135

I put export GDK_CORE_DEVICE_EVENTS=1 to /etc/X11/Xsession.d/56xubuntu-session and my Xfce panel items aren't blinking any more, and that works with Plank too. Tested on Xubuntu 18.04.